# Not all code paths return a value (for google cloud function callable)

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, callable

I have a cloud function and when I use some async functions and put a 'return' in each possible output, I still get *Not all code paths return a value*

I've tried deleting my database calls and just having the 'return {data:{...}};' which makes the error go away.

I have also tried wrapping everything inside a 'try' 'catch' block.

I current have what I would expect to work which is two blocks get().then()...catch()..

```
export const getUsersInHere = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => 
{
    if(!context || !context.auth || !context.auth.uid)
    {
        return {data:{message:"Please login again...", success:false}};
    }
    else if(data)
    {
        const my_uid = context.auth.uid;
        db.collection(`InHere/${my_uid}`).get().then(snapshot => 
        {
           return {data:{}, success:true};
        }).catch(e =>
        {
            return {data:{message:"No last message yet...", success:false}};
        });
    }
    else 
    {
        return {data:{message:"no body sent", success:false}};
    }
});
```

I would expect to be able to deploy my cloud function with *firebase deploy*, instead I am getting deploy errors:

```
src/index.ts:83:62 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

83 export const getUsersInHere = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>
```

**Note** 
I think I've found that 'firestore deploy' works when I added 'async' into the signature of the callable, however the 'warning/error' still remains in Microsoft Studio Code (Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030))

export const getUsersInThisChatRoom = functions.https.onCall(**async** (data, context) =>

Comment: hi, no. taking out the final else makes it possible to return nothing. I get: src/index.ts:83:63 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value. 

I'm noticing I can deploy by adding async into the function signature onCall, though I still see a warning

Comment: Your `else if` branch doesn't return anything. Those return statements return from the inner functions declared when calling `then` and `catch`.

Comment: ah, I got it, I think I need to use 'await', then, since it appears onCall does not give the possibility of using 'callbacks'/completion blocks ? yes I think that does the trick. if you'd like to post, I would accept that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With callables, you can either directly return the object to be serialized and sent to the client, or you can return a promise that resolves with the object to send.  All you have to do is return the promise in your `else if` block:

```
    // note the return added to the next line
    return db.collection(`InHere/${my_uid}`).get().then(snapshot => 
    {
        return {data:{}, success:true};
    }).catch(e =>
    {
        return {data:{message:"No last message yet...", success:false}};
    });
```

This will return the promise that resolves to either value you returned from the `then` or `catch` callback.

You have no obligation to use async/await, but if you do, you should completely replace your then and catch blocks with proper async/await syntax.  It will look very different.