# Nodejs cloud functions - Not all code paths return a value

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function to create a node in firebase realtime database. The code seems to be returning a value for all paths. Where is it that i am going wrong? Is there a scenario where `gamesRef.push()` is not called and is that the reason the error is being thrown?

Cloud Function:

```
export const createGame = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const game_type = data.game_type;
    if (game_type != GAME_PRACTISE || game_type != GAME_MULTIPLAYER || game_type != GAME_FRIENDS) {
        return {
            "status": 403,
            "id": null
        };
    } else {

        const uid = data.uid;
        const status = GAME_STATUS_OPEN;
        var players = [uid];

        let max_players;
        if (game_type == GAME_PRACTISE) {
            max_players = 1;
        } else if (game_type == GAME_MULTIPLAYER) {
            max_players = 10;
        } else if (game_type == GAME_FRIENDS) {
            max_players = 50;
        }

        let db = admin.database();
        let gamesRef = db.ref("/games");

        gamesRef.push({
            ... // data to be inserted
        }).then(res => {
            return {
                "status": 200,
                "id": gamesRef.key
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            return {
                "status": 403,
                "id": null
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` here:

```
return gamesRef.push({
    ... // data to be inserted
}).then(res => {
    return {
        "status": 200,
        "id": gamesRef.key
    }
}).catch(error => {
    return {
        "status": 403,
        "id": null
    }
});
```

Without that top-level `return`, nobody will ever see the return values from your `then` and `catch` callbacks.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, that solved my issue.

Comment: The top-level return, is this how callable functions work? Shouldn't the return inside the then or catch are enough to return the values? Sorry if its a dumb question, new to nodejs and cloud functions

Comment: Ok i see what you mean from this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502767/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value-for-google-cloud-function-callable